# How to take a username from a form and put into a paragraph html

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the username from the login `<input id="Username" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Username or Email"  value="" name="username">` and put it in the    `<p id="user8"></p>`
but I don't know how.

User.html

```
    <body>
    <header>      
    <nav id="nav">       
    <ul>
    <li><a id="h" class="navbar" href="mainpage.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="a" class="navbar" href="About.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a id="c" class="navbar" href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/Logo.png" alt="hii"></a>
    <img id="user" src="img/user-01.png" alt="">
    <p id="user8"></p>
    <br>
    <a id="Signout" href="index.html">Sign Out</a>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

Login.html

```
<body>
 <h6>SBE3</h6>
  <form name="Login" >
  <div class="login">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2 id="title1">Login</h2>
      <hr>


        <div class="input">
          <input id="Username" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Username or Email"  value="" name="username">
          <hr>
          <br>
          <input  id="Password" type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password" name="Password" value="">
          <hr>
          <br>
          <label id="rm" for="rm">Remember me</label>

          <input id="rm" type="checkbox" name="" value="remember me">
          <br><br>
          <a id="Acc" href="Signup.html">Create An Account</a>
          <br><br><br>
          <input type="button"  onclick="validateForm()" id="button" value="Login" />
         

        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="req1"></p>
    <p id="req2"></p>
    </form>
```

cj.js

```
function validateForm() {
  let username = document.getElementById('Username');
  let password = document.getElementById('Password');


  if (Username.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("req1").innerHTML = "*Username required";
    Username.focus();
  }
  if (Password.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("req2").innerHTML = "*Password required";
    Password.focus();
    return false
  }

  window.location.replace("user.html");

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the login form submit to a server script that checks the username and password? Why are you just redirecting directly to `user.html`?

Comment: And `validateForm()` should return if the username is blank. it will redirect if the username is blank but the password is filled in.

Comment: You can store the username in `localStorage`, then JavaScript on `user.html` can read this and put it into the `user8` element.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("username", Username.value);`

Comment: @barmar I don't know how to make the form submit to a script that checks the name and username

Comment: @barmar do i put `localStorage.setItem("username", Username.value);` in a new function or `validateForm()` or just in the java script file    i am sorry but i am very new to this

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how you write server scripts to process forms. You can do it in any server language you like: PHP, Python, Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the username to local storage in `validateForm`.

BTW, you assigned variables `username` and `password`, but then used `Username` and `Password`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

```
function validateForm() {
  let Username = document.getElementById('Username');
  let Password = document.getElementById('Password');


  if (Username.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("req1").innerHTML = "*Username required";
    Username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (Password.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("req2").innerHTML = "*Password required";
    Password.focus();
    return false
  }
  
  localStorage.setItem("username", Username.value);

  window.location.replace("user.html");

}
```

Then on `user.html` retrieve it and put it in the `<p>`.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let username = localStorage.getItem("username");
  if (username) {
    document.getElementById("user8").innerText = username;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I applied the code to my files and the login button dosen't take me to the user.html page

Comment: Are you getting an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: yes it is saying `cj.js:23 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`          and `Login.html:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Login.html:32)`

Comment: Sorry, typo, I was missing the `)` at the end of the `setItem` call.

Comment: Why didn't you mention that first? Surely the first place you look when you have problems with JavaScript is the console, I shouldn't have to ask for that.

Comment: i fixed the errors it is working now thank you you have been so helpful